# Are Neos clones?

Tags: the-matrix

If a) previous Neos look the same on the screens in the Architect's room, b) "our" Neo looks the same in the Matrix and in Zion, and c) and Zion exists in base-reality, then that means previous Neos were almost certainly biological clones, right?

Comment: I believe [your answer can be found here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12506/how-could-all-versions-of-neo-look-identical/13632#13632).

Comment: Those _are_ good answers. Thanks!