# How do the machines rebuild Zion in "The Matrix"?

Tags: the-matrix, the-animatrix

If the machines rebuild Zion after destroying it, how do they most likely rebuild it?

I mean, do they take a bunch of humans out of the matrix and just drop them there? Do they implant false memories? What about the personal belongings of the previous inhabitants? Isn't it suspicious the lack of historic records? What about the humans born without plugs? Do the machines provide clothing, food, habitation? Do the machines teach humans about technology, etc.?

Does all this beg the question? How do the machines rebuild Zion without humans realizing it's a trap? Was this explained?

Comment: My gut instinct is that the machines repair Zion after they've trashed it. The One takes a bunch of people out of the Matrix and they wander around for a bit before "discovering" Zion and occupy it.

Comment: Note that the humans are blissfully unaware that it's 700+ years later than they think it is, so historic records clearly isn't a problem.

Comment: Is kind of a long shot. Took a bunch of people out of the matrix,  It would be very very suspicious to find a fully stocked (with cloth, food weapons, ships, sanitation, water, furniture, electrical system, medical facilities, etc) place and don't find any human of record what happened.

Comment: You know what they say about gift horses and mouths

Comment: I'm not sure that I clearly remember that it's the machines who do the rebuilding, do we have a ref for that?

Comment: Re: a mix of things. Some slices of this get aired out in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221788/why-did-the-people-of-zion-never-find-evidence-of-the-previous-cycles/. I don't recall anything affirming the machines rebuild, but the question of how the humans bootstrap Zion's infra _is_ an elephant in the room. I'm bearish on _our Neo_ being "he who freed the first of us" and leaving w/ the 23 (reasoning after #3 in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/221830/60794). If The One is a program with a purpose, I guess there may be a matching archetype to lead them out?

Comment: @eli.rodriguez, although not stated, it's implicit that records do exist; after all, the current residents of Zion (and their ancestors) know something about the history of the war. The Machines could fake all sorts of records and leave them for humans to find, just enough to reconstruct what they think happened.

Comment: @eli.rodriguez they could have "stumbled" upon an unused bunker. They know that there was a war and that it was the humans who "scorched the sky", trying to stop the machines at the ultimate cost of annihilating all other life on Earth so it is not a super far stretch that there WOULD be multiple bunkers somewhere, fully stocked